# Undefined index when defining PHP POST inside JQuery variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok so i am using Ajax to display a note on the screen when people click on a note name on the left and the note will show on the right.

Now when a user edits the note they should be able to click a button and it saves the new text back to the ID the note was originally loaded from.

Basically i can get the note id in PHP but then how do i pass that ID to jquery to then use.

My script:

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
    {
        $showNoteInfo = "SELECT Note, NoteName FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = " . $_POST['noteid'];
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
    {
        if (empty($_POST['noteid'])) 
        {
            $notes = 'No Data';
        }
        if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) 
        {
            $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo "<div class='custom-font title-container'>
                    <div class='expand-button-container fa fa-expand' onclick='expandWindow()'></div>
                    <div id='title-container1'><div class='edit-note fa fa-pencil' onclick='editGeneralNote()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" . $data['NoteName'] . "&nbsp;<div class='save-note fa fa-thumbs-up' onclick='saveGeneralNote(); submitNoteText();'></div></div>
                  </div>";
            echo "<textarea spellcheck='false' readonly id='ta1'>" . $data['Note'] . "</textarea>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "No data found";
        }
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Submit generalNote to the database

function submitNoteText()
{
    var noteid = <?php echo $_POST['noteid']; ?>;
    var notetext = $("#ta1").val();

    var dataString = 'noteid1=' + noteid + '&notetext1=' + notetext;

    console.log("NoteID: " + noteid);

    if(noteid == ''||notetext == '')
    {
        alert("NoteID or Text is blank");
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "phpFiles_Notes/submitNoteText.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
```

As you can see im trying to put the function in the same php file so i can directly use $_POST['noteid'] which holds the id i want.

So why is it saying that in my function the Index is Undefined when at the top it has an 'isset' on the id and retrieves the ID no problem?

Comment: `var noteid = <?php echo $_POST['noteid']; ?>;` is not inside any check for the index's existence.

Comment: You can use like this... 
`var noteid = <?php if(isset$_POST['noteid']){ echo $_POST['noteid'];}  ?>;`

Comment: With new versons of php, you'll wan't to use filter_input( INPUT_POST, "you_variable", FILTER_YOU_WANT_TO_APPLY ). You might look at http://php.net/manual/fr/filter.filters.sanitize.php and http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @AbhishekMishra if you put that as answer i will mark it as answer as that worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this...

```
var noteid = <?php if(isset$_POST['noteid']){ echo $_POST['noteid'];} ?>;
```